# Tsql Update row with same ID and latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I update row U with the same ID2 and latest date. I am able to write the select clause:

```
SELECT  ID2
        , MAX(Date)
FROM    TABLE
GROUP BY    ID2
```

but I have problem with update clause.

I have table:

```
ID1 |ID2    |Date       |U
1    1       2015-02-18  NULL 
2    1       2015-02-11  NULL
3    2       2015-02-17  NULL
4    2       2015-02-14  NULL
5    2       2015-02-11  NULL
6    3       2015-02-14  NULL
7    3       2015-02-10  NULL
```

What I want to achive:

```
ID1 |ID2    |Date       |U
1    1       2015-02-18  Update 
2    1       2015-02-11  NULL
3    2       2015-02-17  Update 
4    2       2015-02-14  NULL
5    2       2015-02-11  NULL
6    3       2015-02-14  Update 
7    3       2015-02-10  NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

I will do this using `CTE` with `Row_Number window function`

```
;with cte as
(
select ID1 ,ID2 ,Date ,U, Row_Number() over(partition by ID2 order by Date desc) rn 
From Yourtable
)
update Cte set U = 'Update'
where RN=1
```

When there is a `tie` in `max` date per `ID2` then use `Dense_rank` to update both the records.

```
;with cte as
(
select ID1 ,ID2 ,Date ,U, Dense_Rank() over(partition by ID2 order by Date desc) rn 
From Yourtable
)
update Cte set U = 'Update'
where RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use your SELECT...MAX query to filter the TABLE. Something like this;

```
UPDATE T SET U = 'UPDATE' 
FROM T JOIN (
SELECT  ID2
        , MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
FROM    TABLE
GROUP BY    ID2) AS X ON X.ID2 = T.ID2 AND X.MaxDate = T.Date
```

One point to note about this approach is that if there is more than 1 record with the max Date per ID2 then all records with the max Date will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

interesting way to achieve this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.U='Update'
FROM TestTable T1
WHERE 0=(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TestTable T2 WHERE T1.ID2=T.ID2 AND T1.Date<T2.Date)
```